# What are the practical differences between an AsyncIterable and an Observable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, rxjs, observable

I've been hung up about this topic lately. It seems AsyncIterables and Observables both have stream-like qualities, though they are consumed a bit differently.

You could consume an async iterable like this

```js
const myAsyncIterable = async function*() { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; }

const main = async () => {
  for await (const number of myAsyncIterable()) {
    console.log(number)
  }
}

main()
```

You can consume an observable like this

```js
const Observable = rxjs
const { map } = rxjs.operators

Observable.of(1, 2, 3).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

My overarching question is based off of this [RxJS pr](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/5297)

> If the observable emits at a pace faster than the loop completes, there will be a memory build up as the buffer gets more full. We could provide other methods that use different strategies (e.g. just the most recent value, etc), but leave this as the default. Note that the loop itself may have several awaits in it, that exacerbate the problem.

It seems to me that async iterators inherently do not have a backpressure problem, so is it right to implement `Symbol.asyncIterator` (@@asyncIterator) on an Observable and default to a backpressure strategy? Is there even a need for Observables in light of AsyncIterables?

Ideally, you could show me practical differences between AsyncIterables and Observables with code examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "*default to a backpressure strategy*"?

Comment: You seem to already have answered the question from the title in the body (async iterables are pull-based, observables are push-based). Do you really want to know about the difference?

Comment: @Bergi In particular, the backpressure strategy of allowing a memory build-up as the buffer gets more full (as the contributor seems to imply). And no, it does not sound like a good strategy to me. Also, I may have answered my question just a tad bit, but I was looking for something more fleshed out.

Comment: If it's not possible to consider Observables as pull sources, is it right to make Observables async iterable? I also wanted to point out for reference that Observables are in a [stage 1 proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-observable/)

Comment: Can async iterables do everything observables can? Do we need an Observable in the spec?

Comment: Yes, an unbounded buffer is *no* backpressure, that's why I was confused by the wording.

Comment: "*Do we need an Observable in the spec?*" - that's an opinion-based question we cannot answer here. The text of the proposal you linked should make good arguments for that though.

Comment: "*Can async iterables do everything observables can?*" - no. They require a consumer to produce values. Hm, on the other hand the observables in the proposal you linked appear to behave the same.

Comment: Very close (iterator vs iterable) duplicate: [What is the difference between async generators and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48512319/1048572)

Comment: I wish I had found that question, thank you bergi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main difference is which side decides when to iterate.

In the case of Async Iterators the client decides by calling `await iterator.next()`. The source decides when to resolve the promise, but the client has to ask for the next value first. Thus, the consumer "pulls" the data in from the source.

Observables register a callback function which is called by the observable immediately when a new value comes in. Thus, the source "pushes" to the consumer.

An Observable could easily be used to consume an Async Iterator by using a Subject and mapping it to the next value of the async iterator. You would then call next on the Subject whenever you're ready to consume the next item. Here is a code sample

```
const pull = new Subject();
const output = pull.pipe(
  concatMap(() => from(iter.next())),
  map(val => { 
    if(val.done) pull.complete();
    return val.value;
  })
);
//wherever you need this 
output.pipe(

).subscribe(() => {
  //we're ready for the next item
  if(!pull.closed) pull.next();
});
```

Comment: From a consumption perspective, what can an Observable do that an AsyncIterable can't?

Comment: I'm looking for something practical, with code examples

Comment: @richytong Async Iterators on their own would need another way of cancelling operations (AbortSignal for example): Currently there is no way to - once a promise start - to "tell the promise" (thus the AsyncIterator) to cancel. `try { ... } finally { ... }` is used in iterators, but in AsyncIterators will not call the `finally { ... }` part until there is no promise currently being waited on. Hence why IxJS uses AbortSignals whenever creating their AsyncIterator abstraction: https://github.com/ReactiveX/IxJS/blob/master/docs/asynciterable/creating.md#creating-a-sequence-with-create

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3f3c614d8b86c68d271a1db995ff11c61842e757/src/internal/asyncIteratorFrom.ts#L4) is the current implementation `Observable[Symbol.asyncIterator]`.

Here's a basic example of `Symbol.asyncIterator` implemented on an array:

```js
const dummyPromise = (val, time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time * 1000, val));

const items = [1, 2, 3];

items[Symbol.asyncIterator] = async function * () {
  yield * await this.map(v => dummyPromise(v, v));
}

!(async () => {
  for await (const value of items) {

  console.log(value);
}
})();
/* 
1 - after 1s
2 - after 2s
3 - after 3s
*/
```

The way I understand generators(**sync** generators) is that they are **pausable functions**, meaning that you can request a value right now and another value 10 seconds later. The async generators follow the same approach, except that the value they produce is **asynchronous**, which means that you'll have to `await` for it.

For instance:

```js
const dummyPromise = (val, time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time * 1000, val));

const items = [1, 2, 3];
items[Symbol.asyncIterator] = async function * () {
  yield * await this.map(v => dummyPromise(v, v));
}

const it = items[Symbol.asyncIterator]();

(async () => {
  // console.log(await it.next())
  await it.next();

  setTimeout(async () => {
    console.log(await it.next());
  }, 2000); // It will take 4s in total
})();
```

---

Going back to the `Observable`'s implementation:

```js
async function* coroutine<T>(source: Observable<T>) {
  const deferreds: Deferred<IteratorResult<T>>[] = [];
  const values: T[] = [];
  let hasError = false;
  let error: any = null;
  let completed = false;

  const subs = source.subscribe({
    next: value => {
      if (deferreds.length > 0) {
        deferreds.shift()!.resolve({ value, done: false });
      } else {
        values.push(value);
      }
    },
    error: err => { /* ... */ },
    complete: () => { /* ... */ },
  });

  try {
    while (true) {
      if (values.length > 0) {
        yield values.shift();
      } else if (completed) {
        return;
      } else if (hasError) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        const d = new Deferred<IteratorResult<T>>();
        deferreds.push(d);
        const result = await d.promise;
        if (result.done) {
          return;
        } else {
          yield result.value;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    subs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

From my understanding:

- `values` is used to keep track of **synchronous values**
  If you have `of(1, 2, 3)`, the `values` array will contain `[1, 2, 3]` before it even reached `while(true) { }`. And because you're using a `for await (const v of ...)`,
  you'd be requesting values as if you were doing `it.next(); it.next(); it.next() ...`.

  Put differently, as soon as you can consume one value from your iterator, you're immediately requesting for the next one, until the data producer has nothing to offer.
- `deferreds` is used for **asynchronous values**
  so at your first `it.next()` , the `values` array is empty(meaning that the observable did not emit synchronously), so it will fall back to the last `else`, which simply creates a promise that is added to `deferreds`, after which that promise is `await`ed until it either `resolves` or `rejects`.

  When the observable finally emits, `deferreds` won't be empty, so the awaited promise will `resolve` with the newly arrived value.

```js
const src$ = merge(
  timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(1)),
  timer(2000).pipe(mapTo(2)),
  timer(3000).pipe(mapTo(3)),
);

!(async () => {
  for await (const value of src$) {
    console.log(value);
  }
})();
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-async-iterables?file=index.ts)

Comment: When already working with a queue of promises yourself, it's much easier (and more efficient) to [implement the async-iterator interface yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157577/1048572) than using an async generator function.

Comment: Interesting! Your answer reminds me of dataloader. Thank you. I personally find this approach easier to grasp, although it may not be the most efficient

Answer (score 1):

The observable stuff is mind-bending, and my understanding could be flawed.  An async iterator is an iterator that yields promises, with each promise resolving to a future event within a continuously updating stream of events (a hot observable).  It could be implemented using a queue as follows.

```js
function* iterateClickEvents(target) {
  const queue = []
  target.addEventListener('click', e => queue.shift()?.fulfill(e))
  while (true)
    yield new Promise(fulfill => queue.push({fulfill}))
}

//use it
for await (const e of iterateClickEvents(myButton))
  handleEvent(e)
```

Then you can implement fluent operators like:

```js
class FluentIterable {
  constructor(iterable) {
    this.iterable = iterable
  }
  filter(predicate) {
    return new FluentIterable(this.$filter(predicate))
  }
  async* $filter(predicate) {
    for await (const value of this.iterable)
      if (predicate(value))
        yield value
  }
  async each(fn) {
    for await (const value of this.iterable)
      fn(value)
  }
}

//use it
new FluentIterable(iterateClickEvents(document.body))
  .filter(e => e.target == myButton)
  .each(handleEvent)
  .catch(console.error)
```

https://codepen.io/ken107/pen/PojZjgB

You could implement a `map` operator that returns the results of *inner* iterators.  Things get complicated from there.